# Make Ivy recognize ant#ant and ant#org.apache.ant are conflicts

Tags: ivy

My build has both ant-1.7.0.jar and ant-1.6.2.jar in it, and this is breaking tests. Looking at the ivy:report, it appears that 1.6.2 is resolved as ant#ant, and 1.7 is ant#org.apache.ant.

So how can I configure Ivy to treat ant and org.apache.ant as the same organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't but you can create a global [exclusion](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/exclude.html):

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    ..
    ..    
    <dependencies>
        ..
        ..
        <!-- Global exclusions -->
        <exclude org="ant" module="ant"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```